# Can I find out if string to ANSI conversion will result in loss of data?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ansi

Say, when I convert a string into a byte array using single-byte encoding, some characters will be replaced with '?':

```
string strData="©";
byte[] bytesData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData);
```

Is there any way to find out if a string will lose some of it's data if I convert it to ANSI?

PS. I'm not inquiring about benefits of Unicode encodings, such as UTF-8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about?

```
Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strData)) == strData;
```

Answer (score 3):

If you instantiate your own `Encoder`  you can specify an [`EncoderFallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder.fallback.aspx), one of the pre-defined such objects is [`EncoderFallback.ExceptionFallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoderfallback.exceptionfallback.aspx) which will:

> throws an exception when an input character cannot be encoded

Comment: +1 On (very) large strings this will be clearly the better solution.